# Blurry Images when rendering to PDF using UIKit/Coregraphics

Tags: ios, pdf, uikit, core-graphics, pdf-generation

Everything seems pretty standard I downloaded [PDF GENERATION SAMPLE](http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/) and used my own assets at normal resolutions and my images look a little off.

Here's the asset [image: source]

Here's what it looks like in app [image]

And this is what it looks like in the PDF at 100% zoom[image]

The code in the drawImage function is as simple as it gets

```
UIImage * demoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_map_project.png"];
[demoImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - demoImage.size.width)/2,
                                 350,
                                 demoImage.size.width,
                                 demoImage.size.height)];
```

Nothing fancy at all. I do admit that my familiarity with the details of how PDF work, DPI, and things like that are beyond me at this point.

I've looked at LibHaru and think it's a great system but I'd rather keep this within the confines of UIKit/CoreGraphics.

You'll notice a strange jaggedness on the right side, even shrinking the image down by 50% doesn't seem to help.

Here's a zoomed up image using Digital Color Meter with the PDF at 100% and then the app [image]

As you can see the image simply does not render correctly into the PDF and I'm struggling to find a solution for this.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you verified that `(pageSize.width - demoImage.size.width)/2` is an integer?  If either `pageSize.width` or `demoImage.size.width` is odd and the other is even, then the origin of your rectangle will not be an integer, so it won't be on a pixel boundary (on a non-Retina screen).

Comment: I tested it changing the rect's X to be a integer but to no avail. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You draw the image in the PDF in a rectangle that matches the image size. This results in a 72dpi for the image. Because the viewer application use 96dpi or a higher value as reference for 100% zoom, when the file is displayed at 100% your image will be rendered 100% * 96/72 scale. If you enlarge the bitmap at that scale with an imaging tool you'll see a similar jaggedness. The solution is to use a larger image drawn in a 37x36pt rectangle so that the resulting image dpi is higher.
If you zoom your PDF file to 75% the image size displayed on the page should match the image size in your application (this assumption is based on a 96 dpi screen).

Comment: I suspected as much. I'll start shrinking down my images, or enlarging them if my source permits.
I had one more question, do you know why zooming in and out of pdfs causes these artifacts? The left image is at 100% and the other is zoom very far inward. You'll notice in the small image there are small artifacts on the top and right side of the ball. The image is scaled down by half but there was some rounding down when it was scaled down, the original image was 45, 44.
http://i.imgur.com/svnRVS8.png

Comment: There are 2 possible causes for the artifacts: 1. CoreGraphics might resample the image when inserts it in the PDF file (this is an assumption, I do not know for sure); 2. The scaling algorithm used by the viewer application to display the image. There is nothing you can do here.